# Django client certificate prompt

Tags: python, django, ssl

Newbie to django/ssl here.
I am trying to implement a service where it should prompt client certificate to select a list of client certificates in a browser. Once client selects one, I need to get that certificate values in my django application for further processing.
Currently django application runs behind apache.
The question is:
-How do I enable the prompt to select a certicate from client?
-Is it from apache or django?
can anybody provide the documentation for that to work?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should enable a client certificate prompt at **apache** level.
Once it's properly configured the certificate can be passed to **django** via ENV variables and then you'll be able to read and handle it in your django app.

More details:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient

http://stuff-things.net/2015/09/28/configuring-apache-for-ssl-client-certificate-authentication/

But note you may have browsers compatibility issues with this approach so it requires extensive cross-browser testing